# How to make just part of a macro hygienic

Tags: lambda, scheme, callcc, r6rs, hygiene

I'd like to have a version of `lambda`, called `lambda-r`, from within which you can `return`. An example:

```
(+ ((lambda-r ()
    (return 1)
    2)) 5)
```

This would give the value `6`. Although you might expect the value to be 7, it's 6 because 1 is returned from the lambda-expression before 2 is reached.

Here's an example of the kind of transformation I'm looking for. Let's say one were to use `lambda-r` as follows:

```
(lambda-r (a b)
    (return a)
    (+ a b))
```

I want it to be transformed like this:

```
(call/cc (lambda (k)
       (define return (lambda (v)
                        (k (lambda (a b)
                             v))))
       (lambda (a b)
         (return a)
         (+ a b))))
```

That could also be expressed with a let-expression instead of an internal define, but I'm using the define for clarity's sake.

Note that the above code does actually work as expected. **The problem** is that I'm having trouble expressing `lambda-r` as a *macro*. The reason is that I want `k` and `v` to be hygienic, but I don't want `return` to be hygienic.

My macro at the moment is this:

```
(define-syntax lambda-r
  (syntax-rules (return)
    [(_ (var ...) body ...)
     (call/cc (lambda (k)
           (define return (lambda (v)
                            (k (lambda (var ...)
                                 v))))
           (lambda (var ...)
             body ...)))
     ]))
```

Which doesn't work because `return` is treated hygienically, and as a result isn't directly visible when using `lambda-r`. So `(lambda-r () (return 1))` gives an error which says that `return` isn't a valid identifier.

---

Edit: Thanks to Nathan Sanders' answer, I'm closer to understanding what I have to do here. However I don't fully understand the following procedures, and as a result haven't been able to get this working yet. I'd really appreciate if you could explain/direct me to resources which explain the following:

- the `syntax`  procedure
- the `datum->syntax`/`syntax->datum` procedures

Edit: Nevermind - I've got it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `syntax-case` instead of `syntax-rules`.

[The R6RS definition](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-13.html) gives some examples, notably [a section on syntax-object and datum conversions](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-1.html#node_toc_node_sec_12.6), which is what you want. You should be able to adapt the `loop` w/ `break` example to your `return`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I'm looking for. I've been reading through that page and it's a bit tough to digest; can you explain what the `syntax` procedure does? Also helpful would be an easier-to-understand description of `with-syntax`, and `datum->syntax`/`syntax->datum`.

Comment: I can't edit that comment anymore, but it's still annoying me: I *now understand those terms :)